# Placing links inside markdown code blocks

Tags: github, hyperlink, markdown

I want to have links inside my code blocks using GitHub flavored markdown.

````
```cpp
void Click ([Keycode](#keycode) key) const
```
````

Unfortunately, it renders that as code, anyway to make it a link instead?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as I know, the current instance of [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown) doesn't support this.

The all block is rendered with `<div class="highlight highlight-html"><pre>... </pre></div>`, meaning your markdown link is not interpreted.

It would be best to place that link just *before* the code section (unless said section has dozens of similar links in your code).

Comment: `highlight-html` can vary depending on the detected language, but the point remain: everything is wrapped in pre, which means any code (markdown or html) won't be interpreted.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure you're right. For me it was more of a design issue but I think I found a way around it (see my answer).

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Your answer achieves a good workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 44):

If its a short piece of code this should do the trick:

`` [`this is code`](https://this_is_url/) ``

Answer (score 20):

As suggested by VonC, it might not be possible with the current version of [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown). That being said, I did find a way around it which suits my requirements. By using tags like `<big>`, `<pre>` and `<b>` I'm able to simulate syntax highlighting and get the effect I'm looking for. Too bad I can't add my own color though.

```
<big><pre>
**void** Click ([**Keycode**](#keycode) key) **const**
</pre></big>
```

Comment: +1, but your original question was about the possibility to include a link (something on which you can click), not just about the visual aspect. So my answer stands.

Comment: I'm not disputing your answer, simply offering an alternative.

Comment: You don't need the `<big>` tags.  Just precede the `<pre>` tag with a space.

Comment: But `<big>` more closely presents like a code block does with `\`\`\`` so I'm glad he recommended it.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this using HTML in markdown, yes, even on Github:

```
<pre>
<a href="my-url">Something</a>
</pre>
```

Comment: A concise version of this (in markdown) could be <pre> [Something][] </pre>. See reference links in https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link

Answer (score 4):

This makes the trick.

I use it on my GitHub profile page to put links inside code blocks.

```
<pre>
 <code>
  <a href="https://github.com/gmarciani">gmarciani</a>
 </code>
</pre>
```