# Print tab space and hyperlinks in discord.js [v12]

Tags: format, discord.js

I would like to print a tab space and also a hyper link in the description of a message embed.
Using `\t` along with three ` will print a tab space and `[click](https://example.com)` makes a hyper link.

However, I want to combine these to so I get `<tab space> <hyperlink>`

I have noticed that using 3 ` together with `\t` and `[click](https://example.com)` will print the tab space, but instead of printing the hyper link, it prints exactly like this `<tabspce> [click](https://example.com)`

Comment: I'm not sure if I can understand you correctly. Do you want to have a clickable link inside a code block (i.e. three backticks)?

Comment: yes, but before the clickable like, I need to include a tab space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placing links inside markdown code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092433/placing-links-inside-markdown-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Using a blank emoji instead of `\t` worked.

This is the emoji I used `<:Blank:850603065760284722>`